# Excel VBA: Auto Increment ID Number inside of Text

Tags: excel, vba

I have here the sample code of how the auto increment ID Number and sample output of the program

[image]

```
Sub AddData()
Dim ws As Worksheet 'define worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

Dim Deadline As Range 'define deadline range
Set Deadline = ws.Range("H1")

Dim Submitted As Range 'define submitted range
Set Submitted = ws.Range("H3")


Dim nRow As Long 'find next free row = last used used row +1
nRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

ws.Cells(nRow, "A").Value = "ABC-00" & nRow & ""
ws.Cells(nRow, "B").Value = Deadline.Value
ws.Cells(nRow, "C").Value = Submitted.Value
End Sub
```

As you can see, I have 3 different fields. ID, DEADLINE, SUBMITTED

Whenever I enter a new record for deadline and submitted field the id should automatically increment based on the last inserted id.

As you notice, the first ID is ABC-001 and It suddenly jump into ABC-003 instead of ABC-002.

As I guess maybe the reason is, it follows the row # of the data that's why after ABC-001 it shows up as ABC-003 because this ID number is row #3

Is there any way to get the last inserted ID and be a basis for generating new id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way I would program this task: just take the last used and add 1.

```
Sub AddData()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim AbcID As Range
    Dim Deadline As Range
    Dim Submitted As Range
    Dim AbcNum As Integer

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")          'define worksheet
    With Ws
        Set AbcID = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)  'last used
        Set Deadline = .Range("H1")                     'define deadline cell
        Set Submitted = .Range("H3")                    'define submitted cell
    End With

    With AbcID
        If .Row > 1 Then AbcNum = Val(.Value)
        Set AbcID = .Offset(1)
    End With

    With AbcID
        .Value = AbcNum + 1
        .NumberFormat = """ABC""" & "-000"
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = Deadline.Value
        .Offset(0, 2).Value = Submitted.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ws.Cells(nRow, "A").Value = "ABC-00" & nRow & ""
```

to

```
ws.Cells(nRow, "A").Value = "ABC-00" & (nRow - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer was a cell phone.
Your "nRow" is the original number plus one. So you have to subtract 1 again.
For correct results, you must set the digit to 3 digits. If you are over 10 and over 100, you can tell the difference.
Simply concatenating the characters (00 & 1) will result in different results later.

```
ws.Cells(nRow, "A").Value = "ABC-" & Format(nRow - 1, "000")
```